# Can't see existing folders/files in WebDAV

Tags: 2013, webdav, iis7

We recently upgraded from Tridion 2011 SP1 to 2013 SP1. On 2011, we had WebDAV setup and it was perfectly working. But after the upgrade, the connection to WebDAV works, but I can't see the existing folders/files.

When I upload a new file to WebDAV, it is visible in the SDL Tridion UI..But when my colleague goes back to the same WebDAV folder, he doesn't see it. We both are admins as well. I know this is something to do with IIS but not sure what and where the issue is with permissions etc. Can someone help?

os: Windows Server 2008 R2

Observed one more thing. The parent has pdf and images folders. I am able to see old assets from images, but not pdf. So pdf folder is the only one in issue.. any thoughts here?

Hello Trevor, Bart, please find some additional information:

From Webdav logs:

Error in DefaultWebDavCartridge_WebdavUtilities_CheckBCErrors: Item not found.
Error in DefaultWebDavCartridge_WebdavUtilities_ExecuteBCRequest: Item not found.

From Tridion IIS logs:

No items found for WebDAV URL(s):

/webdav/**/Building%20Blocks/Content/Multimedia%20Components/pdf/desktop.ini.

Component: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService

Errorcode: 512

User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

StackTrace Information Details: at Tridion.ContentManager.UrlConversion.Convert() at Tridion.ContentManager.Session.GetTcmUri(String uri) at Tridion.ContentManager.Session.GetObject(String uri) at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceBase.GetSubject(String id, ReadOptions readOptions) at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceBase.Read(String id, ReadOptions readOptions) at SyncInvokeRead(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) at System.ServiceModel.Di

@Nuno: Thank you. Yes, we have a support ticket with SDL, will keep posted of how it goes.

Comment: What is the relation between this question and http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4775/tridion-2013-sp1-webdav-not-loading-all-multimedia-components it sounds like a duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is fixed here in Hotfix TT 87728

Release Notes for Hotfix TT 87728

Version: 
    This hotfix is intended for SDL Tridion 2013 SP1.

Problem description:
    WebDAV http handler failing for folders with names the same as a one of the file extensions defined for multimedia types

Hotfix description:
    WebDAV http handler was wrongly determining the type of a folders with names the same as a one of the file extensions defined for multimedia types, as a component. This fixes addresses this issue.

Answer (score 7):

We have always had issues with the allowed verbs in the IIS Request Filtering module for our company. Look at the web logs for the IIS site and check for any 400 erros around your webdav path. You can also turn on the Failed Request Trace Logging within IIS and it will give you a deep dive through the stack. If it was working before, the upgrade may have blown away your settings for IIS. Just a thought...

Post back with an update if you find any web log errors.

Answer (score 5):

I got intrigued by this and did some investigations that seem to confirm your findings...

- If I create a folder, then put a MM item in it, it doesn't show in WebDAV
- I also get the same warning in Event Viewer about /webdav/blah blah
- Using that WebDav Url from a CoreService client does load the object, so nothing wrong there

If I do the same thing, but create first a normal component on this new folder, then all multimedia components show as expected. This definitely qualifies as a defect in my book...

I assume you opened a support ticket already, and I would expect to see a fix for this soon.

PS - Tested on Windows Server 2012 R2, Tridion 2013 SP1, Windows 8.1 webdav client

**EDIT** After additional investigation, it seems this only happens when the folder name matches a multimedia type - if your folder is named "PDF" or "GIF" of "JPG", this will happen, but if you name it "PDF2", then it won't happen. The plot thickens...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like if the actual folder in Tridion is called "PDF" then the PDF will not show up in WebDAV. If you rename the folder to something like "PDFs" then PDF will show up in WebDAV. Very strange....